# Reading text file and dealing with numbers

Tags: matlab, for-loop, text, binary

I'm attempting to count the number of letters in a text file, but unfortunately I keep getting stuck if numbers are involved.

So far I have been able to deal with letters and symbols, but unfortunately the ischar function doesn't help me when it comes to numbers.

```
function ok = lets(file_name)
fid = fopen(file_name, 'rt');
if fid < 0
    ok = -1;
end
C = [];
D = [];
oneline = fgets(fid);

while ischar(oneline)
    C = oneline(isletter(oneline));
    W = length(C);
    D = [D ; W];
    oneline = fgets(fid);
end
total = 0;
for i = 1:length(D)
    total = D(i) + total;
end
ok = total;
```

How can I deal with counting letters if there are also numbers in a text file?

Comment: Can you post a small sample file and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I approached the problem the following way:

```
function ok = lets(file_name)

file    = memmapfile( file_name, 'writable', false );
lowercase = [65:90];
uppercase = [97:122];
data = file.Data;
ok = sum(histc(data,lowercase)+histc(data,uppercase));

end
```

I mapped the file to memory using the [`memmapfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memmapfile.html) function and compared the data with the character encodings from [this ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/). Lower case letters are represented by `[65:90]` and upper case letters by `[97:122]`. By applying the [histc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) function, I got the frequency in which each letter appeared in the file. The total number of letters is given by adding all the frequencies up.

Note that I called `histc` twice to avoid having a bin from `90` to `97`, which would count the []^_` characters.

I applied the function to a sample file called *sample.txt* containing the following lines:

```
abc23D&f![
k154&¨&skj
djaljaljds
```

Here is my output:

```
>> lets('sample.txt')
Elapsed time is 0.017783 seconds.

ans =

    19
```

**Edit:**

Outputting `ok=-1` for problems reading file:

```
function ok = lets(fclose(fid);file_name)
try
    file    = memmapfile( file_name, 'writable', false );
catch
    file=[];
    ok=-1;
end
if ~isempty(file)
    lowercase = [65:90];
    uppercase = [97:122];
    data = file.Data;
    ok = sum(histc(data,lowercase)+histc(data,uppercase));
end

end
```

With `fopen` approach, since you get the `ok=-1` "by default":

```
function ok = lets(file_name)
fid = fopen(file_name, 'rt');
if fid < 0
    ok = -1;
else
    celldata=textscan(fid,'%s');
    fclose(fid);
    lowercase = [65:90];
    uppercase = [97:122];
    data = uint8([celldata{1}{:});
    ok = sum(histc(data,lowercase)+histc(data,uppercase));
end

end
```

Comment: How would I modify this function if I wanted to the output to be -1 if there was a problem opening the file?

Comment: I'd wrap it up in a try catch statement. If it has trouble opening the file you can assign ok=-1. The same idea applies if I were to use fread. Otherwise I'd use fopen to open the file since you need this -1 which is standard to fopen. Check my edit

Comment: Fantastic, thank you again for your help. This is a big help in terms of learning MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making this a lot more complected than it needs to be, just use `isletter` like you had and then use `length`.

```
function ok = lets(file_name)
%Original code as you had it
fid = fopen(file_name, 'rt');
if fid < 0
    ok = -1;
 end
%Initialize length
ok = 0;
%Get first line
oneline = fgets(fid);

%While line isn't empty
while oneline ~= -1
    %remove everythin that's not a letter
    oneline(~isletter(oneline)) = [];
    %Add number of letters to output
    ok = ok + length(oneline);
    %Get next line
    oneline = fgets(fid);
end
end
```

I used the input file,

```
Ar,TF,760,2.5e-07,1273.14,4.785688323049946e+24,24.80738364864047,37272905351.7263,37933372595.0276
Ar,TF,760,5e-07,1273.14,4.785688323049946e+24,40.3092219226107,2791140681.70926,2978668073.513113
Ar,TF,760,7.5e-07,1273.14,4.785688323049946e+24,54.80989010679312,738684259.1671219,836079550.0157251
```

and got `18`, this counts the `e`'s in the numbers, do you want these to be counted?